MJML with Freemarker
I want to use MJML with Freemarker in Java.
My template :
<mj-raw>
    <#if ( typeDemande == "hydrocurage" ) >d'de</#if>
</mj-raw>

But When I compile (MJML 5):

SyntaxError: Unexpected closing tag "#if".

Any solution ? Thanks

No idea about MJML specifically, but can you configure FreeMarker to use square bracket syntax, like [#if typeDemande == "hydrocurage"]d'de[/#if]? (BTW, the () in the if is redundant.)

It works perfectly <3 Thanks
